# HTML table position is deteriorating when I fill the tables with javascript

Tags: html, jsp

I have a .jsp page in my project. The jsp page has 2 html table. The first position of tables is like this

[image: first position]

When I fill the tables with javascript codes, it looks like this

[image: second position]

I don't want the tables position to change. I want them side by side like first position but I didn't make it. So is there any suggestion for my issue?

My html codes like this

```
<div style="margin-left:7%; margin-right:10%;">
        <div style="margin-right: 45%;">
            <table id="example_table" class="table table-primary table-bordered table-sm table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="font-size:11px;">
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:8%;">Group</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:8%;">Doc.Name</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:8%;">Customer</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:8%;">Operator</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:8%;">Status</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:2%;">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="font-size:11px;"></tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr style="font-size:11px;">
                        <th class="text-center">Group</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Doc.Name</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Customer</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Operator</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:58%; margin-top:-72px;">
            <table id="example_table_2" class="table table-primary table-bordered table-sm table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="font-size:11px;">
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:8%;">Details</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:2%;">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="font-size:11px;"></tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr style="font-size:11px;">
                        <th class="text-center">Details</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<div style="display:flex;"">
        <div style="margin-right: 5%;">
            <table id="example_table" class="table table-primary table-bordered table-sm table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="font-size:11px;">
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:8%;">Group</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:8%;">Doc.Name</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:8%;">Customer</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:8%;">Operator</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:8%;">Status</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:2%;">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="font-size:11px;">
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td>Test LOng Data Sentence</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td>Delete</td>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr style="font-size:11px;">
                        <th class="text-center">Group</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Doc.Name</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Customer</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Operator</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 5%;">
            <table id="example_table_2" class="table table-primary table-bordered table-sm table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="font-size:11px;">
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:8%;">Details</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:2%;">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="font-size:11px;">
                <td>Test LOng Data Sentence</td>
                <td>Delete</td>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr style="font-size:11px;">
                        <th class="text-center">Details</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```